# What is the meaning of "in which"?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

What is the meaning of "in" when it comes before "which" in the following example?

> An inverted sentence is a sentence in a normally subject-first language in which the predicate (verb) comes before the subject (noun). [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_sentence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "which" in your example refers to "a sentence in a normally subject-first language", and **in** that sentence, the predicate comes before the subject.

Here are some more examples:

> The house **in which** he lived only had one window. = He lived **in** a house **which** only had one window.
>
> This is a movie **in which** the main character falls in love with his enemy. = **In** this movie, the main character falls in love with his enemy.
>
> Poker is a card game **in which** players bet real money. = **In** the card game  of poker, players bet real money.

The main word here is "which", referring to the house, the movie, and the game, respectively. The "in" comes from the fact that you're talking about what's **in** the house, **in** the movie and **in the game**.

You can combine "which" with other conjunctions like "with" and "for", for example:

> The woman **with which** you came to the party just left. = The woman you came to the party **with** just left.
>
> This is a crime **for which** the country will never forgive you. = This is a crime the country will never forgive you **for**.